# Clang wrongly chooses GCC's include directories

Tags: c++, linux, clang

I installed LLVM+Clang from apt.llvm.org repositories using the `apt` package manager. But I can't use it properly.

```bash
$ clang++ -E -v -
Debian clang version 15.0.7
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: .;@m64

...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /include
 /usr/include
```

It doesn't contain the actual path to Clang's `libc++` headers. Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

enum A { B };
int main() { std::is_scoped_enum_v<A>; }
```

It fails to compile:

```bash
$ clang++ main.cc -std=c++2b
main.cc:4:19: error: no member named 'is_scoped_enum_v' in namespace 'std'
int main() { std::is_scoped_enum_v<A>; }
             ~~~~~^
main.cc:4:36: error: 'A' does not refer to a value
int main() { std::is_scoped_enum_v<A>; }
                                   ^
main.cc:3:6: note: declared here
enum A { B };
     ^
main.cc:4:38: error: expected expression
int main() { std::is_scoped_enum_v<A>; }
                                     ^
3 errors generated.
```

While it's completely compilable code: https://godbolt.org/z/YP33v7Y9a

How could I fix it?

---

Environment:

- OS: `Debian Buster`
- Kernel: `4.19.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.269-1 (2022-12-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- GCC: `(Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0`
- Clang: `Debian clang version 15.0.7`

**How did I install LLVM+Clang?** 
Using `apt` in Debian Buster from those repositories copied from https://apt.llvm.org:

`deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-15 main 

deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-15 main`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the known behavior, it uses the system default GCC C++ runtime on Debian and Ubuntu for making built app less dependent on other libraries. Use `-stdlib=libc++` if you want to use Clang C++ libraries:

```
$ clang++ -E -v -stdlib=libc++ -
$ clang++ main.cc -std=c++2b -stdlib=libc++
```